# What is the simplest way in Python to plot a line profile of an image for a specific value of y, specifying the start and end point of the line?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, scikit-image

I have an image of the moon like this:
[moon picture from normal camera lens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39yfI.jpg)

I want to plot the intensity profile along a line for a fixed value on the y axis, that runs along the image like this:
[image above with line across a fixed y coordinate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5T9T.png)

I want to be able to specify the start and end point of the coordinate by typing it into my Python code. I found a way to do this using mouse clicks and other methods, however cannot get a result that is only the profile along the same line because I need to compare this image's profile at the specific value of y, to another image at that same value of y. Using clicks is innacurate and I cannot replicate results.

How can I do this?

I was able to do this for another image but I cannot get rid of the red line in the profile plot (see code below)

[another image and profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvqQR.png)

Code for another image and profile:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from skimage.measure import profile_line
from skimage.io import imread


image = imread(r".....path to image....\moon2.png")

start = (210, 100) #Start of the profile line row=100, col=0
end = (210, 410) #End of the profile line row=100, col=last

profile = profile_line(image, start, end)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].set_title('Image')
ax[0].imshow(image)
ax[0].plot([start[1], end[1]], [start[0], end[0]], 'r')
ax[1].set_title('Profile')
ax[1].plot(profile)


plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30,70)
```

Comment: is your issue how to remove a plotted line? then that's purely a ***matplotlib*** usage question

Answer (score 0):

You can use "hyperspy" package to easily do this. Probably there are more straightforward (commonly used packages) that do the same. I am not an expert but the following will surely work.

```
import hyperspy.api as hs
```

First, load the image

```
s = hs.load("spam.jpg")
```

Then plot it.

```
s.plot()
```

#Then define the 2d-line object with x1,y1, x2,y2

```
line_profile = hs.roi.Line2DROI(1,1,3,1)
```

#Extract data along the defined line interactively

```
line0 = line_profile.interactive(s)
```

## You can plot the line profile on the same figure

```
hs.plot.plot_spectra(line0)
```

For more information refer here:
http://hyperspy.org/hyperspy-doc/current/user_guide/visualisation.html#plotting-several-signals